# Tkinter Window Displays Blank in PyCharm but Works in Terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm developing an application using Tkinter in Python, and I've encountered a peculiar issue. When I run the script through my Anaconda environment in the terminal on my laptop, it works perfectly. However, when I try to run the same script in PyCharm (also on my laptop), the Tkinter window displays, but it remains blank - none of the widgets (specifically the tiles I've created) are visible.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Confirmed that PyCharm is using the same Python interpreter and
  environment as my terminal where the script runs successfully.
- Checked for any errors in the PyCharm console but didn't find anything that points to the issue.
- Simplified the Tkinter code to test if basic elements like buttons display correctly (they do).
- Made sure the mainloop() is being called.

I suspect the issue might be related to how PyCharm handles Tkinter windows or possibly an issue with the canvas or frame configuration in my code, but I'm not sure.

Here's a snippet of my Tkinter setup:

Copy code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def populate_frame():
    # ... (logic to populate tiles)

populate_frame()

root.mainloop()
```

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can offer insight into why the Tkinter window would behave differently in PyCharm compared to running the script directly in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few more things u could try:

**1.**
U should ensure that your terminal and PyCharm using the same version of Tkinter.
For that, use:

```
print(tk.TkVersion)
```

**2.**
If your application involves complex graphics, there might be differences in how PyCharm and the terminal handle graphics rendering. Ensure that your graphics rendering code is compatible with both environments (an old friend of mine had this issue, but I don't know how he resolved it).

**3.**
Try to update PyCharm, maybe thats the problem